# Can find the determinant of a matrix A of size $n$ in terms of the traces of $A^m$

Tags: matrices, trace

We can find the determinant of a matrix A of size $n$ in terms of the traces of $A^m$, for $m=1,…,n$ ?

It's det of a matrix with term are traces, but i saw  but i can't remember

[Expressing the determinant in terms of the trace of a matrix and the trace of its square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939495/expressing-the-determinant-in-terms-of-the-trace-of-a-matrix-and-the-trace-of-it) when $n=2$.

Comment: see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668374/determinant-of-a-finite-dimensional-matrix-in-terms-of-trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If the eigenvalues of $A$ (counting algebraic multiplicity) are $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$, then:

- $\det A = \lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$;
- $\text{tr }A = \lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n$;
- the eigenvalues of $A^k$ are $\lambda_1^k, \ldots, \lambda_n^k$, and in particular, $\text{tr}(A^k) = \lambda_1^k + \cdots + \lambda_n^k$.

With these facts in hand, apply [Newton's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).