# About a matrix identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

In a document named as "The Matrix Cook-Book" I saw two expressions of which I do not get any clue how they are derived.

For $n = 3:$
$\det(I + A) = 1 + \det(A) + Tr(A) + 1/2\ Tr(A)^2 − 1/2\ Tr(A^2)$

And  for $n = 4:$

$\det(I + A) = 1 + \det(A) + Tr(A) + 1/2\ Tr(A)^2 − 1/2\ Tr(A^2)+1/6\ Tr(A)^3 − 1/2\ Tr(A)Tr(A^2) + 1/3\ Tr(A^3)$

I see that if we can express $\det(I + A)$ in this way many sums will be easier to solve.

Comment: I just noticed some homework problems about expressing the determinant in terms of the trace. I suspect, these might be related. Unfortunately, that book is at my office for now. Well, maybe this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668374/determinant-of-a-finite-dimensional-matrix-in-terms-of-trace

Comment: This phenomenon is probably best understood in terms of the characteristic polynomial; plugging in $t=-1$ gives you equations of this sort.

Comment: As a remark, the Matrix Cookbook is all about real or complex matrices. The two expressions can be meaningless (not to say true) over some finite fields (such as $GF(2)$).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to generate these formulas is to write everything in terms of eigenvalues.  Then
$$ \det(I+A) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1 + \lambda_i) = \sum_{i=0}^n e_i(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n) ,$$
where the $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Then you convert the elementary symmetric polynomials into power sum symmetric polynomials as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial remembering that
$$ \text{Tr}(A^k) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^k .$$